# dynamic parameter to an endpoint

Tags: xpath, apache-camel, endpoint

How to set a dynamic value as a parameter to an endpoint?

Payload :

```
<person>
<name>john</name>
<acno>9876543210</acno>
</person>
```

route :

```
<route>
    <from uri="http://localhost:8092/test/"/>
    <setProperty propertyName="acno">
            <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//person/acno</xpath>
    </setProperty>
    <setProperty propertyName="name">
            <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//person/name</xpath>
    </setProperty>
    <to uri="https://server/rest/services/test?accountno=${property.acno}&amp;accountname=${property.name}"/>
</route>
```

The parameter value want to take from the payload by xpath.
Any help in resolving this issue or providing a workaround would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dynamic content from headers inside endpoint URIs.

What you can do is to preconstruct the URI by using some xpath or whatever and put it into a header. Then you can use the [Recipient List](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) construct to use that dynamicly created URI.

You have some examples in the link

**Update:** see this [link](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) suggested by Claus Ibsen in comment

Comment: Yes see also this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html